# Google Foobar Level 4 RunningWithTheBunnies

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, graph-theory, floyd-warshall

I am stuck on one test case for the foobar problem.

Question and my code are given below

> You and your rescued bunny prisoners need to get out of this
> collapsing death trap of a space station - and fast! Unfortunately,
> some of the bunnies have been weakened by their long imprisonment and
> can't run very fast. Their friends are trying to help them, but this
> escape would go a lot faster if you also pitched in. The defensive
> bulkhead doors have begun to close, and if you don't make it through
> in time, you'll be trapped! You need to grab as many bunnies as you
> can and get through the bulkheads before they close.
>
> The time it takes to move from your starting point to all of the
> bunnies and to the bulkhead will be given to you in a square matrix of
> integers. Each row will tell you the time it takes to get to the
> start, first bunny, second bunny, ..., last bunny, and the bulkhead in
> that order. The order of the rows follows the same pattern (start,
> each bunny, bulkhead). The bunnies can jump into your arms, so picking
> them up is instantaneous, and arriving at the bulkhead at the same
> time as it seals still allows for a successful, if dramatic, escape.
> (Don't worry, any bunnies you don't pick up will be able to escape
> with you since they no longer have to carry the ones you did pick up.)
> You can revisit different spots if you wish, and moving to the
> bulkhead doesn't mean you have to immediately leave - you can move to
> and from the bulkhead to pick up additional bunnies if time permits.
>
> In addition to spending time traveling between bunnies, some paths
> interact with the space station's security checkpoints and add time
> back to the clock. Adding time to the clock will delay the closing of
> the bulkhead doors, and if the time goes back up to 0 or a positive
> number after the doors have already closed, it triggers the bulkhead
> to reopen. Therefore, it might be possible to walk in a circle and
> keep gaining time: that is, each time a path is traversed, the same
> amount of time is used or added.
>
> Write a function of the form answer(times, time_limit) to calculate
> the most bunnies you can pick up and which bunnies they are, while
> still escaping through the bulkhead before the doors close for good.
> If there are multiple sets of bunnies of the same size, return the set
> of bunnies with the lowest prisoner IDs (as indexes) in sorted order.
> The bunnies are represented as a sorted list by prisoner ID, with the
> first bunny being 0. There are at most 5 bunnies, and time_limit is a
> non-negative integer that is at most 999.
>
> For instance, in the case of   [
> [0, 2, 2, 2, -1],  # 0 = Start
> [9, 0, 2, 2, -1],  # 1 = Bunny 0
> [9, 3, 0, 2, -1],  # 2 = Bunny 1
> [9, 3, 2, 0, -1],  # 3 = Bunny 2
> [9, 3, 2, 2,  0],  # 4 = Bulkhead   ]   and a time limit of 1, the five inner array rows designate the starting point, bunny 0, bunny 1,
> bunny 2, and the bulkhead door exit respectively. You could take the
> path:
>
> Start End Delta Time Status
> -   0     -    1 Bulkhead initially open
> 0   4    -1    2
> 4   2     2    0
> 2   4    -1    1
> 4   3     2   -1 Bulkhead closes
> 3   4    -1    0 Bulkhead reopens; you and the bunnies exit With this solution, you would pick up bunnies 1 and 2. This is the best
> combination for this space station hallway, so the answer is [1, 2].
>
> Test cases Inputs:
>
> (int) times = [[0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1,
> 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]]   (int) time_limit = 3   Output:
>
> (int list) [0, 1]   Inputs:
>
> (int) times = [[0, 2, 2, 2, -1], [9, 0, 2, 2, -1], [9, 3, 0, 2, -1],
> [9, 3, 2, 0, -1], [9, 3, 2, 2, 0]]   (int) time_limit = 1   Output:
>
> (int list) [1, 2]

Adding my code below.

```
public class RunningWithBunnies {

    public static class FloydWarshall {

        private final Integer[][] allPairShortestPathMatrix;
        private final Integer[][] pathFinderMatrix;

        public FloydWarshall(final Integer[][] matrix) {

            if (matrix.length != matrix[0].length) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad Adj Matrix Passed");
            }

            allPairShortestPathMatrix = new Integer[matrix.length][matrix[0].length];
            pathFinderMatrix = new Integer[matrix.length][matrix[0].length];
            for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                    allPairShortestPathMatrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j];
                    if(matrix[i][j] != null) {
                        pathFinderMatrix[i][j] = j;
                    }
                }
            }
            findAllPairsShortestPath(matrix);
        }

        public int getShortestDistanceBetweenNodes(final int startNode, final int endNode) {
            return allPairShortestPathMatrix[startNode][endNode];
        }

        public List<Integer> findShortestPathBetweenNodes(final int startNode, final int endNode) {

            final List<Integer> path = new ArrayList<>();
            Integer currentNode = startNode;
            path.add(startNode);

            while (currentNode != endNode) {

                currentNode = pathFinderMatrix[currentNode][endNode];
                if (currentNode == null || allPairShortestPathMatrix[currentNode][currentNode] < 0) {
                    return Collections.emptyList();
                }
                path.add(currentNode);
            }

            return new ArrayList<>(path);
        }

        public boolean doesMatrixContainNegativeCycles() {

            for (int i = 0; i < allPairShortestPathMatrix.length; i++) {
                if (allPairShortestPathMatrix[i][i] < 0) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        private void findAllPairsShortestPath(final Integer[][] matrix) {

            for(int k = 0; k < matrix.length; k++) {
                for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
                    for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {

                        final Integer directPathCost = allPairShortestPathMatrix[i][j];
                        final Integer indirectPathToIntermediateCost = allPairShortestPathMatrix[i][k];
                        final Integer indirectPathFromIntermediateCost = allPairShortestPathMatrix[k][j];

                        if (indirectPathToIntermediateCost != null && indirectPathFromIntermediateCost != null) {
                            if (directPathCost == null ||
                                (directPathCost > indirectPathToIntermediateCost + indirectPathFromIntermediateCost)) {
                                allPairShortestPathMatrix[i][j] = allPairShortestPathMatrix[i][k] + allPairShortestPathMatrix[k][j];
                                pathFinderMatrix[i][j] = pathFinderMatrix[i][k];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static int[] solution(int[][] times, int times_limit) {

        final Integer[][] matrix = new Integer[times.length][times[0].length];
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = times[i][j];
            }
        }
        final FloydWarshall floydWarshall = new FloydWarshall(matrix);

        final Set<Integer> bunniesLeft = IntStream
            .range(1, matrix.length - 1)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        if (floydWarshall.doesMatrixContainNegativeCycles()) {

            return bunniesLeft
                .stream()
                .mapToInt(bunny -> bunny - 1)
                .toArray();
        }

        final List<Integer[]> path = new ArrayList<>();

        int currentPos = 0;
        int pathCost = 0;
        while (!bunniesLeft.isEmpty()) {

            int nearestBunnyPathDuration = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            int nearestBunny = -1;
            for (int bunnyPosition : bunniesLeft) {

                if (bunnyPosition != currentPos
                    && bunniesLeft.contains(bunnyPosition)
                    && floydWarshall.getShortestDistanceBetweenNodes(currentPos, bunnyPosition) < nearestBunnyPathDuration) {

                    nearestBunnyPathDuration = floydWarshall.getShortestDistanceBetweenNodes(currentPos, bunnyPosition);
                    nearestBunny = bunnyPosition;
                }
            }

            if (nearestBunny == -1) {
                break;
            }

            final List<Integer> subPath =
                floydWarshall
                    .findShortestPathBetweenNodes(currentPos, nearestBunny)
                    .stream()
                    .filter(bunniesLeft::contains)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            currentPos = nearestBunny;

            for (int subPathNode : subPath) {

                path.add(new Integer[]{
                    subPathNode,
                    path.isEmpty()
                        ? floydWarshall.getShortestDistanceBetweenNodes(0, subPathNode)
                        : pathCost + floydWarshall.getShortestDistanceBetweenNodes(path.get(path.size() - 1)[0], subPathNode)
                });
                bunniesLeft.remove(subPathNode);
                pathCost = path.get(path.size() - 1)[1];
            }
        }

        path.removeIf(pathNode ->
            pathNode[1] + floydWarshall.getShortestDistanceBetweenNodes(pathNode[0], matrix.length - 1) > times_limit
        );

        if (path.isEmpty()) {
            return new int[]{};
        }

        return path
            .stream()
            .mapToInt(node->node[0] - 1)
            .sorted()
            .toArray();
    }
}
```

Only Test Case 8 is failing. I have seen other solutions in stack overflow, but none have taken this approach. Would appreciate any pointers as to what I am missing here.

Thanks!

Comment: I once figured out an unhandled case for a different foobar problem by hard-coding different answers that might happen for edge cases until the failing test passed (and all other tests failed). That helped me understand which edge case was not handled.

Comment: Hey, I tried that, and got the answer, its {0,2,4}.. issue is I cannot think of any reason why this wont be solved by my code.. the numbers are sorted, its not part of negative cycle.. so still kind of stumped